# match enything except the content between specific tags

Tags: regex

I am struggling with regexp matching. In my case i need to select all characters except for those between specific tags. My text would look like:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [original]don't select this[/original], sit epicuri qualisque id.`

'and I want just Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' + , 'sit epicuri qualisque id' to be selected text. I've tried selecting all characters than excluding my phrase but I don't get it. 
If I put those into groups than only first occurence works, but if more those tags are present i can't get the desired result.

Any tips on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of capturing groups and grab everything in your capturing group that you want.

```
^((?:(?!\[original\]).)+)\[original\](?:(?!\[\/original\]).)+\[\/original\](.+)$
```

This will put everything before the tag in capturing group 1, and everything after in capturing group 2. The whole match matches the entire line, but the tag and everything between it is not being capturing in a group.

NOTE: This won't work if there is more than one tag. If you want that, please edit your question to reflect that.

tested on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tL1uM5/1)

Comment: Thanks R Nar, quite close, bat as you noticed I need more tags to be able to appear in text. I modified the question to reflect that as well

Comment: @bigcat In that case, I have a feeling that this would be better achieved without the use of regex.

Comment: any ideas how R Nar? I need the selected text to manipulate after selection, to apply a filter, and then to echo it, keeping the text between [original] unchanged. Any ideas appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As R Nar suggested I used another approach, combinations of regex and split/join to achieve desired result.

First I used split in javascript to create an array of words

`let words = input.split(/([original]|[/original])/);`

Once splitted I applied transformations on desired parts, and once transformations are done, I used join method to put everything back together.

`input = words.join("");`